# Почему Gulp билдит не все файлы?

Tags: gulp

Половину файлов создает (картинки, страницы), половину нет.

```
   var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    rigger = require('gulp-rigger'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin'),
    rimraf = require('rimraf'),
    wait = require('gulp-wait'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    nunjucks = require('gulp-nunjucks'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    reload = browserSync.reload;

var path = {
    build: {
        html: 'build/',
        js: 'build/js/',
        css: 'build/css/',
        img: 'build/img/',
        fonts: 'build/fonts/',
        libs: 'build/libs'
    },
    src: {
        html: 'src/**/*.html',
        js: 'src/js/main.js',
        jsapp: 'src/js/app.js',
        style: 'src/style/main.scss',
        img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*',
        libs: 'src/libs/**/*.*'
    },
    watch: {
        html: 'src/**/*.html',
        js: 'src/js/**/*.js',
        style: 'src/style/**/*.scss',
        img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*'
    },
    clean: './build'
};

var config = {
    server: {
        baseDir: "./build"
    },
    // tunnel: true,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9000,
    logPrefix: "Frontend_Devil"
};

gulp.task('html:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.html)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(nunjucks.compile({name: 'Sindre'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('js:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.jsapp)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(rigger())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('style:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.style)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(wait(100))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 20 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('image:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.img)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('fonts:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts))
});

gulp.task('libs:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.libs)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.libs))
});

gulp.task('build', [
    'html:build',
    'js:build',
    'style:build',
    'fonts:build',
    'image:build',
    'libs:build'
]);

gulp.task('webserver', function () {
    browserSync(config);
});

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    watch([path.watch.html], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('html:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.style], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('style:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.js], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('js:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.img], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('image:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.fonts], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('fonts:build');
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перед `gulp.src` должен стоять `return`, иначе галп не сможет понять когда заканчивается таск.

Comment: Спасибо! Проблема решена.